# Is there any differences between "p = &i" and "*p = i" while assigning the address int "i" to a pointer "p"

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I found this piece of code in my C programming book:

```
int i = 42;
int *p;

p = &i;    // & is address of sign
*p = i;    // * is dereference sign
```

Is there any difference between "p = &i" and "*p = i"??
Will "p" have different characteristics while using these two expressions???

Edit: Because this code is just trying to explain the concept of the pointer, it is not runnable... So the order of these two assignments is not relevant in this case... Sorry for making things vague...

Comment: My bet is that the book writers were trying to say that *p == i  Which is a true statement.

Comment: Try to switch between the two assignments and see what happens

Comment: Completely different. The first assigns the address, the second assigns the value.

Comment: A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address in memory where something else can be found. `p = &i;` assigns the address in memory where `i` is stored as the value held by pointer `p`. (`p` now points to the memory where `i` is stored) To reference the value at the address held by a pointer you *dereference* the pointer by using the unary `'*'` character before the pointer name. `*p = i;` would set the value at the memory location held (pointed to) by `p` to the value of `i`.

Comment: The order of the assignments is *completely* relevant.  Switching them results in using an undefined pointer, which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any differences between “p = &i” and “*p = i” while assigning the address int “i” to a pointer “p”

Yes, there is a huge difference. Only `p = &i` means "assign the address of `i` to `p`".

On the other hand `*p = i` means "assign the value of `i` to the value at the address that is stored in `p`". You can see the results with a simple example:

```
int i = 42;
int* p;

p = &i;
printf("%d", i);
*p = 5;
printf("%d", i);

int j = 3;
printf("%d %d", i, j);
p = &j;
*p = i;
printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

Comment: In the question example `*p = i;` doesn't do anything because it assigns the value of  `i` to where `p` is pointing, which is `i`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, if you do `p = &i` and then `*p = i;` immediately afterwards is pointless. My answer is attempting to explain the two syntaxes in isolation. Do you have any suggestions how to make that more clear?

Comment: My comment was an attempt to illustrate what is happening, and I voted you up.

Comment: I would also simplify the second part - `assign the value of i to the value at the address that is stored in p` --> `store the value of i in the memory address pointed to by p`, but maybe i'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: @WeatherVane This piece of code is all about the concept of the pointer... so `p = &i` and `*p = i` come together...

Comment: @Billy The problem is that they do two different things. When you have those two statements in a row, you won't see anything happen and will have a difficult time understanding what they each do. Hopefully my answer clarifies the difference by using two different variables `i` and `j`.

Comment: So `p` in `*p = i` will have its own address but point to the value of `i` while `p` in `p = &i` will just give the address of `i`... am I right?

Comment: @Billy I proved to myself by doing some experiments about it... I am right.  <br/>`p` in `*p = i` will have the address that assigned to the `p`, although `p` will have the value of `i`, `p` will reserve the address it got. 
 <br/>And `p` in `p = &i` will simply make the `p` have the address of `i`. 
 <br/>@Code-Apprentice Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Billy Yes, in order to use `*p`, `p` must already be initialized to a valid address. This is the same as initializing any variable such as `int i;` before you try to use `i`. So if you assign `p` to an address, for example with `&p = j` in my example in this answer, then you can assign the value at that address to the value of `i` with `*p = i`.

Comment: @Billy "although p will have the value of i, p will reserve the address it got" More accurately, **the memory that `p` points to** will have the value of `i`. `p` itself doesn't change; it just has an address.

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick summary - given the declaration

```
int i, *p;
```

and the statement

```
p = &i;
```

then the following are true:

```
 p == &i // int * == int *
*p ==  i // int   == int
```

You've assigned the *address* of `i` to `p`.  Thus, the *expressions* `*p` and `i` evaluate to the same thing.  Assigning a value to `*p` is the same as assigning a value to `i`, reading a value from `*p` is the same as reading a value from `i`.  If you later did something like

```
*p = 10;
```

Then this is the same things as writing

```
i = 10;
```

IOW, you're assigning a new value to the thing `p` *points to*.

If we introduce multiple levels of indirection, like:

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
int **q = &p;
```

then the following are all true:

```
  q == &p         // int ** == int **
 *q ==  p == &i   // int *  == int *  == int *
**q == *p ==  i   // int    == int    == int
```

Thus, writing to `**q` is the same as writing to `*p` is the same as writing to `i`.  Writing to `*q` is the same as writing to `p`.

---

The following may or may not be helpful.

I've written a small utility that displays the contents of various items in memory, and I'm going to use that to illustrate the difference between `p = &i` and `*p = i`.

First, here's the test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  int i = 0, j = 0, *p = NULL;
  char *names[] = { "i", "j", "p", "*p"};
  void *addrs[] = { &i, &j, &p, NULL };
  size_t sizes[] = { sizeof i, sizeof j, sizeof p, sizeof *p };

  puts( "Before any assignments: ");
  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 3, stdout );

  p = &i;
  addrs[3] = p;

  puts( "After p = &i: " );
  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 4, stdout );

  *p = 42;
  puts( "After *p = 42: " );
  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 4, stdout );

  p = &j;
  addrs[3] = p;

  puts( "After p = &j: " );
  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 4, stdout );

  *p = 10;
  puts( "After *p = 10: " );
  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 4, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

The `dumper` function displays the state of the various objects in memory at that time.

So, we start with the declarations:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, *p = 0;
```

`i` and `j` are regular `int`s, `p` is a *pointer* to `int`.  That means the values stored in `p` are the addresses of other `int` objects.  Here's what things look like in memory at this point:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee3d07a28   00   00   00   00    ....

          j  0x7ffee3d07a24   00   00   00   00    ....

          p  0x7ffee3d07a18   00   00   00   00    ....
             0x7ffee3d07a1c   00   00   00   00    ....
```

`i` occupies 4 bytes starting at address `0x7ffee3d07a28`<sup>1</sup>, `j` occupies four bytes starting at address `0x7ffee3d07a24`, and `p` occupies *eight* bytes starting at address `0x7ffee3d07a18`.  All three objects currently store 0 values.

Next, we execute the statement

```
p = &i;
```

This stores the *address* of `i` to `p`.  Here's how things look afterward:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee3d07a28   00   00   00   00    ....

          j  0x7ffee3d07a24   00   00   00   00    ....

          p  0x7ffee3d07a18   28   7a   d0   e3    (z..
             0x7ffee3d07a1c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

         *p  0x7ffee3d07a28   00   00   00   00    ....
```

Instead of storing all zeros, `p` now stores the address of `i`<sup>2</sup>.  Notice that the *expression* `*p` has the same effective address as the *object* `i`<sup>3</sup>.

Now we execute the statement

```
*p = 42;
```

Here's how our memory looks now:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee3d07a28   2a   00   00   00    *...

          j  0x7ffee3d07a24   00   00   00   00    ....

          p  0x7ffee3d07a18   28   7a   d0   e3    (z..
             0x7ffee3d07a1c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

         *p  0x7ffee3d07a28   2a   00   00   00    *...
```

The least significant byte of `i` now stores the value `0x2a`, which is `42` in hexadecimal.  Note that `*p` shows the same thing.  Again, in most circumstances, `*p` is equivalent to `i`.

Now, we assign the address of `j` to `p`:

```
p = &j;
```

Here's the state of the world now:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee3d07a28   2a   00   00   00    *...

          j  0x7ffee3d07a24   00   00   00   00    ....

          p  0x7ffee3d07a18   24   7a   d0   e3    $z..
             0x7ffee3d07a1c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

         *p  0x7ffee3d07a24   00   00   00   00    ....
```

`p` now stores `j`'s address, and `*p` is now equivalent to `j`.  We finish up by assigning `10` to `*p`:

```
*p = 10;
```

which leaves us with

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee3d07a28   2a   00   00   00    *...

          j  0x7ffee3d07a24   0a   00   00   00    ....

          p  0x7ffee3d07a18   24   7a   d0   e3    $z..
             0x7ffee3d07a1c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

         *p  0x7ffee3d07a24   0a   00   00   00    ....
```

`j` now stores the value `0x0a`, which is hex for `10`. Again, the *expression* `*p` is equivalent to `j`.

---

1. On most systems, the address will change from run to run, so don't get too hung up on the exact address value.

   x86 is little-endian, so the *least* significant byte is the addressed byte.  This means values read "backwards" - left to right, bottom to top.

   This is a bit of dramatic license - *expressions* don't have addresses as such.  This is just to illustrate that the expression `*p` is effectively the same as `i` in most circumstances.